# Why "service not available" when attempting docker pull from google cloud us-docker.pkg.dev

Tags: docker, gcloud

I'm attempting to use docker pull from google cloud us-docker.pkg.dev, why do I get service unavailable?

```
gcloud auth application-default login
OK
gcloud auth configure-docker us-docker.pkg.dev
OK
WARNING: Your config file at [/Users/philandrew/.docker/config.json] contains these credential helper entries:

{
  "credHelpers": {
    "us-docker.pkg.dev": "gcloud",
    "us-east1-docker.pkg.dev": "gcloud",
    "gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "us.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud"
  }
}
Adding credentials for: us-docker.pkg.dev
gcloud credential helpers already registered correctly.

docker pull us-docker.pkg.dev/somename1/somename2/lwutils:1.1.1.5
Error response from daemon: Get "https://us-docker.pkg.dev/v2/": Service Unavailable
```

Answer (score 1):

Your repository path is incorrect.

It needs to be of the form:

`${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev`

Where `REGION` is the [region](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#available) in which your repository was created.